# PHP MySQL Query Where x = $variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause

I have this code (I know that the email is defined)

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `note` FROM `glogin_users` WHERE email = '.$email.'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo $row
?>
```

In my MySQL database I have the following setup
(Table name is glogin_users)
id
email
note

I've tried extracting the note text from the database and then echo'ing it but it doesn't seem to echo anything.

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this? Have you run the query from the command line?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: You can also use `complex syntax` - curly brackets around the variable `WHERE email = ' {$emai} ' ");` . http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 41):

What you are doing right now is you are adding `.` on the string and not concatenating. It should be,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `note` FROM `glogin_users` WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```

or simply

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `note` FROM `glogin_users` WHERE email = '$email'");
```

Comment: In addition to that - `echo $row` won't yield the expected, as `$row` is an array. It should be `echo $row['note']`

Comment: you're welcome `:D` please also read the comment of @Havelock.

Comment: just 1 more problem.

I'm echoing my notes, however there seems to be lots of whitespace before the actual text. 
I'm not really sure on how to deal with this.

Comment: how about trimming it? `trim($row['note'])`

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `note` FROM `glogin_users` WHERE email = '".$email."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo $row['note'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this to echo it:

```
echo $row['note'];
```

(The data is coming as an array)

Comment: also, you got wrong use of dot in the query..