# variable in PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysqli

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703608/php-mysql-query-where-x-variable) (and many many many other places) before i asked my question.

I have tried the following formats `'".$user_id."   ''$user_id'`   and even   `?` to use as my variables holders, but im still getting the same error. I also tried to change from `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

Here's my code.

```
<?php 

    $connection = mysqli_connect("db_name", "user", "pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($con);

    $user_id = $_GET["user_id"];
    $event_id = $_GET["event_id"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM  user where user_id BETWEEN('".$user_id."'+1) and ('".$user_id."'+4);";
    $query .= "SELECT * FROM user_in_event WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND event_id = '".$event_id."' ";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection).$query)   ){
        do {
    /* store first result set */
            if ($result = mysqli_store_result($connection) or die(mysqli_error($con))) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysqli_error($con))) 
                    $array[] = $row;

                mysqli_free_result($result) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                }   

            } while (mysqli_next_result($connection) or die(mysqli_error($con)));
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);

 ?>
```

and this is the error

```
mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli null given
```

and i have checked on the DB itself and the querys works fine

***edit**
fixed "con" to "connection" but now instead of getting the result required im getting balnk

Comment: Are you really using "BWTWEEN" or is it a typo in the question? (should be "BETWEEN")

Comment: okay thanks, i will update the main question because it's still not working  `mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`

Comment: You should create the minimal example with error.  In Your code I see a lot of potential problems. You should use prepared statements too.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_error()` expects the first parameter to be a mysqli resource. In your case you are using an undefined variable `$con` which holds a null value.

A mysqli resource is usually obtained from connecting to the database by calling `mysqli_connect`.

Thus, `$con` should be replaced to `$connection` in `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: Then you likely have more mistakes in your code i. e. when you fetch the values from your database or $array is simply empty.

Comment: for some reason beyond my understanding the same file is now working properly

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT * FROM  user where user_id BETWEEN ('".$user_id."'+1) ... 
try this: 
$query = "SELECT * FROM  user where user_id BETWEEN ('".($user_id+1)."') ...

Comment: got the same result

Answer (score -1):

BETWEEN is looking for simple numbers.
Example
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE Price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;

Your query has some complicated formatting that is probably causing your null value.  I notice you have two ";" where there should be just one to close the query.  It sometimes helps to simplify.

Try creating your search values before the query:

$start=$user_id+1;
$end=$user_id+4;

Then your query becomes
$query = "SELECT * FROM  user where user_id BETWEEN $start and $end";

Hope this helps.